# Virtual box error "Non existent network interface"

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I got an Virtual box image of a Linux Operating System and when I am trying to open it I get the following error.

[image]
The only solution found online was to update the Virtual Box enthernet adapter and if it does not work to reinstall the virtual box.

None of these fixed the problem.

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: `eth0` is Linux network interface naming while you were opening it on Windows. You need to change it to whatever is available in the dropdown list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you've lunched your VM on Windows host, so you need open VM Settings and select one of the available interfaces in "Name:" list.

Comment: Unhelpful, how do you this? There is no such list on my version of VirtualBox.

Answer (score 20):

I had to manually create the vboxnet0 interface

```
$ VBoxManage hostonlyif create
```

and then change the corresponding network settings to ***vboxnet0***

Comment: This command is fine in terms that it really indeed creates that interface, however the problem with it is, it does not work. I just cannot connect to the machine when the interface is created this way. I must figure out, how to get rid of it now, as reinstall did not help. But perhaps running an actual image added to the vbox, creates this interface by the proper way.

Answer (score 4):

Solution for some who have saved states while stuck on a different **network interface**:

1. Close Virtual Box and stop any running services
2. Open the VM's *.vbox* file
3. Replace all occurrences of the network interface from the file with the new card's name (or replace with blank **and** set the status to false)
4. Save and **relaunch** your saved virtual machine
5. Tell me how it went so we can **improve** this answer to help others :)

I hope this helps someone

Comment: Thank you for share. This is the option that worked in my case. But after deleted, it was like vbox remade the configurations correctly for the previous network interface. So i used the same and everything is going well.

Comment: That's great to hear Shad! Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 2):

I had to remove my 'Save State' per [this ticket](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/11183) as I'd moved the VM to a different host while sleeping -- and you can't change the network settings while it's asleep.

Answer (score 0):

Change virtual NIC settings ...attached to NAT..it worked for me [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WWMc.png)